# How do i change the language of the output log of VS2022

Tags: c++, non-english, unreal-engine5

im using UE5 and tried this page
[Change compiler errors language in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529464/change-compiler-errors-language-in-visual-studio-2013)
So i changed the language in the IDE to english and deleted all languages except the english language in VS Installer. I also set the in international languages to english in VS2022
Nothing changed the output log to english. Some stuff they are saying in english like:
Build started: etc. ...
But the errors are in german.

Comment: Have you tried changing the Windows display language `Settings > Time & Language > Language` ?

Comment: yes, it didnt help

Comment: How about the language pack(s) from the MSVS Installer tab `Language Packs` ?

Comment: like i said, i installed just the english version of VS2022 so that didnt work aswell

Comment: some answers???